# inheritance ID column?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, inheritance

Sorry for my English. I'm new here. I try to create a group of tables with sub-tables and I'm stuck. My level of programming is very low so...any advice is apprecied .What I want: Location table to recive ID of prorpietisModel table. I dont understand exactly functionality of spring boot but I try to:)) Anybody some ideas?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="proprieties")
public class ProprietiesModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String test;
    private Location location;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

//

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location extends ProprietiesModel{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String street;
    private int streetNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the concept of JPA `@Inheritance`. Depending on your needs you can choose the inheritance strategy that suits you.

- `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` – the entities from different classes with a common ancestor are placed in a single table
- `InheritanceType.JOINED` – each class has its table and querying a subclass entity requires joining the tables
- `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` – all the properties of a class, are in its table, so no join is required

You can write your Entities as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="proprieties")
@Inheritance(
        strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED
)
public class ProprietiesModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String test;
    private Location location;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location extends ProprietiesModel {
    private String street;
    private int streetNumber;
}
```

You can read more in-depth here:

- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance
- https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/